# Discord.js role/leveling system

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm making a level system for my discord bot, I want it to tell you when you reach a new role, but it tells you every time you level up. I'm pretty new to this so I don't know how to fix it.

I pasted the code for the message leveling system I am using.

```
        if (userStats.level >= 11) {
            message.channel.send(message.author.username + ' you are now Role3 ')
            message.member.addRole(Role3);
            message.member.removeRole(Role2)    
        } 

        else if (userStats.level >= 5) {
            message.channel.send(message.author.username + ' you made it to a Role2 ')
            message.member.addRole(Role2);
            message.member.removeRole(Role1);    
        }                     
        else if (userStats.level >= 1) {
            message.channel.send(message.author.username + ' you made it to Role1! ')
            message.member.addRole(Role1);    
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Is this code called each time a user levels up? Because currently `else if (userStats.level >= 1)` will always evaluate as true for any level above 1. Hence each time a user levels up they will receive a message.

Comment: @Matt They are meant to get a message each level, the only part I guess I dont know how to not repeat per level is `message.channel.send(message.author.username + ' you made it to Role1! ')`